# Downloading only certain MNIST digits

Tags: python, pickle, mnist

I am trying to download only part of the MNIST database of handwritten digits for a project. Specifically, I only want the digits 0, 1, 2 and 3 to be sent to the neural network.

I am currently loading data like this (based on ["Neural Networks and Deep Learning" by Michal Daniel Dobrzanski](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com)):

```
import cPickle
import gzip
import numpy as np

def load_data():
    f = gzip.open('src/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def load_data_wrapper():
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = zip(training_inputs, training_results)
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1])
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = zip(test_inputs, te_d[1])
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)
```

I tried constructing a function creating new data sets from `load_data()` before sending to `load_data_wrapper()` (by changing `tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()` to `tr_d, va_d, te_d = digitTest()` in `load_data_wrapper()`), with no luck, see below:

```
def digitTest():
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    tr_d = list(tr_d)
    va_d = list(va_d)
    te_d = list(te_d)

    newTrD = []
    newTrD.append([])
    newTrD.append([])

    newVaD = []
    newVaD.append([])
    newVaD.append([])

    newTeD = []
    newTeD.append([])
    newTeD.append([])

    for index,label in enumerate(tr_d[1]):
        if tr_d[1][index] < 4:
            newTrD[0].append(tr_d[0][index])
            newTrD[1].append(tr_d[1][index])

    for index,label in enumerate(va_d[1]):
        if va_d[1][index] < 4:
            newVaD[0].append(va_d[0][index])
            newVaD[1].append(va_d[1][index])

    for index,label in enumerate(te_d[1]):
        if te_d[1][index] < 4:
            newTeD[0].append(te_d[0][index])
            newTeD[1].append(te_d[1][index])

    return (newTrD, newVaD, newTeD)
```

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to? How can I do that? Please note that the data is stored in tuples when parsed from the load_data function.

Comment: Please share your solution, later when you have one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used cPickle to load the mnist data set and I do not know what it returns.
Reading your code it seems you did things right however if you say it does not work I suppose somethings off with what or how cPickle returns the data.

I don't have python 2 so i can't debug your code but:

I tend to do these things myself:

```
def loadSet(values_path, labels_path):
    labels = []
    # labels:
    # 0000     32 bit integer  0x00000803(2051) magic number
    # 0008     32 bit integer  28               number of labels
    # 0009     unsigned byte   ??               label
    # 0010     unsigned byte   ??               label
    # ....     unsigned byte   ??               label

    with open(labels_path, 'rb') as f:
        m_number = int.from_bytes(f.read(4,), 'big')
        num_labels = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
        for i in range(num_labels):
            labels.append(int.from_bytes(f.read(1), 'big'))

    images = []
    # images:
    # 0000     32 bit integer  0x00000803(2051) magic number
    # 0004     32 bit integer  60000            number of images
    # 0008     32 bit integer  28               number of rows
    # 0012     32 bit integer  28               number of columns
    # 0016     unsigned byte   ??               pixel
    # 0020     unsigned byte   ??               pixel
    # ....     unsigned byte   ??               pixel

    with open(values_path, 'rb') as f:
        m_number = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
        num_images = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
        num_rows = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
        num_cols = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
        for i in range(num_images):
            image = []
            for x in range(num_rows * num_cols):
                image.append(int.from_bytes(f.read(1), 'big'))
            images.append(image)
```

This function will load a set of mnist labels and values from files. You can grab the data set at http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ and you will have to unzip the files.
Labels would be 'train-labels.idx1-ubyte'. Just pass the path to train labels and images or test labels and images into the function and it will load those values.

Return value is a tuple of two lists:

```
([number], [pixels])
```

where pixels is a list itself.

Also this does no error checking besides throwing exceptions if the file does not exist or (maybe) if its malformed so you might want to consider checking this somehow.

I'm also not used to numpy, I usually work in c++ and java but you sure can convert these values to numpy arrays quite easy - just read up on the topic.

Filtering those is quite easy now and you should be able to use your approach for digitTest now.

As you might see if you use the original mnist data set you only get train and test images. What happens here is that you take a portion of one of the sets and use this as - I'm not entirely sure about your wording here - test data to evaluate training progress. After training has finished you use the 't10k' files to validate how well your networked trained. Important here is that if you split your test data from these t10k images you do not use those again, only the remaining part as the idea is to validate training on data the network has not seen yet.